# Derived vs Stored account balance in high rate transactions system

Tags: mysql, database, spring

I'm writing a Spring Boot 2.x application using Mysql as DBMS. I use Spring Data and Hibernate.
I want to realize a SMS gateway for my customers. Each customer has an account in my system and a balance.

For each sms sent, the balance of the customer must be subctracted by the sms cost. **Furthemore, before send the sms the balance should be checked in order to see if the customer has enough credit (this imply having an updated balance to check).**

I want to handle a high rate of sms because customers are business and not just final users.

Each customer therefore could send hundreds sms in really short time. I'm looking for an efficient way to update customer's balance. Each transaction has a little price but I've a lot of them.

I could derive the balance making a `SELECT SUM(deposit-costs) FROM...` but this would be very expensive to do as soon I've milions of records in my system.
On the other hand, if I keep the value of the balance in a column, I would have two problems:

- concurrency problem: I could have many transactions at the same time that want to update the balance. I could use pessimistic lock but I would slow down the entire system
- correctness of the data: The balance could be wrong due to some wrong/miss update

I could mitigate these points running a task at the end of the day to fix the stored balance with value of the derived one, but:

- if I've hundreds of customers it could stuck my system for some time
- some heedful customer could notice the variation of his balance and could ask for explanation. It's not nice that your balance change without explanation when you are not doing anything

I'm looking for some advice and best practice to follow. In the end several big companies are selling their service "pay as you go", so I guess there is a common way to handle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In banking, people are quite careful about money. Generally, the "place for truth" is the database. You can make the "place for truth" memory, but this is more sophisticated requiring concurrent in memory databases. What if one of your servers goes down in the middle of a transaction? You need to be able to quickly failover the database to a backup.

Do a benchmark to see if database updates times meet your needs. There are various ways to speed them up moderately. If these rates are in your acceptable range, then do it this way. It is the simplest.

A common approach to speed up txn times is to have a threadpool and assign one thread to an account. This way all txns on an account are always handled by the same thread. This allows further optimization.